# Can't save nested_attributes use chosen in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, jquery-chosen

i try build a form using chosen and many to many relation, to store post > categories, i have some troubles

1.- When i create a post i get this message **Unpermitted parameter: categories**

2.- Post is store but categories not saving

Here is my code
**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...

    has_many :post_has_categories
    has_many :categories, through: :post_has_categories

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :post_has_categories,
                                  reject_if: :all_blank,
                                  allow_destroy: true

    serialize :category_ids, Array
    attr_accessor :categories

    # Virtual attributes
    def categories=(ids)
      self.category_ids = ids.split(",").map(&:strip)
    end
end
```

**post_has_category.rb**

```
class PostHasCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :post
      belongs_to :category

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :post
end
```

**categories.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...

    has_many :post_has_categories
    has_many :posts, through: :post_has_categories
end
```

my partial **posts#_form** call data with this

```
<%= f.select :categories, Category.all.map { |c| [c.name_category, c.id] },{}, { class: 'form-control', multiple: true } %>
```

my **posts_controller** in strong_parameters i have this

```
params.require(:post).permit(..., post_has_categories_attributes: [ :post_id, :category_ids ])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your posts#form partial, you should wrap your select element in a `fields_for` method:

```
<%= f.fields_for :has_categories do |hc| %>
  <%= hc.select %>
  <%= hc.select :category_id, Category.all.map { |c| [c.name_category, c.id] },{}, { class: 'form-control', multiple: true } %>
<%= end %>
```

That will ensure that the select method is correctly named to pass the nested attributes.

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-Nested+Attributes+Examples

Comment: Now i get this error `Unpermitted parameter: has_categories` i also edit strong parameters something like params.require(:post).permit(...,:has_categories, post_has_categories_attributes: [ :post_id, :category_id ]) i get the same error